# How can I use multiple lines inside `!If` condition in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using `!If` condition in cloudformation template. Below code has a condition `ShouldAddWebHook` to add or remove `Triggers` in `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` project. When I run deploy command I got this error. Why it complains about `!If` condition?

```
while scanning a simple key
  in "<unicode string>", line 93, column 7:
          !If
          ^ (line: 93)
could not find expected ':'
  in "<unicode string>", line 94, column 9:
            - ShouldAddWebHook
            ^ (line: 94)
```

Below is cloudformation template:

```
Conditions:
    ShouldAddWebHook: !Equals [ !Ref ShouldAddWebHook, "true" ]

Resources:
  CodeBuildProjectDeployment:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name: test
      Artifacts:
        Type: NO_ARTIFACTS
      Environment:
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:2.0
      Source:
        Type: BITBUCKET
        Location: !Ref BitbucketCloneUrl
        GitCloneDepth: 26
        BuildSpec: buildspec.yml
      TimeoutInMinutes: 10
      BadgeEnabled: true
      !If
        - ShouldAddWebHook
        - Triggers:
            Webhook: true
            FilterGroups:
              - - Pattern: PUSH
                  Type: EVENT
        - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `!If` can't be "hanging" like this. It should be associated with some property. You can try the following:

```
Resources:
  CodeBuildProjectDeployment:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name: test
      Artifacts:
        Type: NO_ARTIFACTS
      Environment:
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:2.0
      Source:
        Type: BITBUCKET
        Location: !Ref BitbucketCloneUrl
        GitCloneDepth: 26
        BuildSpec: buildspec.yml
      TimeoutInMinutes: 10
      BadgeEnabled: true
      Triggers:
        !If
          - ShouldAddWebHook
          - Webhook: true
            FilterGroups:
              - - Pattern: PUSH
                  Type: EVENT
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Comment: Your solution works. But why can't I put `!If` on top of `Triggers`? Isn't `Triggers` a property?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) "Fn::If intrinsic function in the metadata attribute, update policy attribute, and property values in the Resources section and Outputs sections of a template". So it must be a value of some property.